# How to create an interactive HTML5 Canvas using event handlers

Tags: html, canvas

I want to create a series of interactive areas in a canvas. The number of areas are dynamic so I cannot hardcode the coordinates.

Im adding the areas to a click event handler like this...

```
$('#FootprintCV').click(function (e) {
    var clickedX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var clickedY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    if (clickedX < area1.right && clickedX > area1.left && clickedY > area1.top && clickedY < area1.bottom) {
             console.log('Area1 clicked at X: ' + clickedX + " Y:" + clickedY);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add objects to an array and iterate on the array whenever a click occurs...

Create an array and objects containing coordinates for your areas

```
var clickShapes = [];
clickShapes.push(shapeObject1);
clickShapes.push(shapeObject2);
clickShapes.push(shapeObject3);
```

When the click is picked up, iterate on the array to catch the event.

```
$('#FootprintCV').click(function (e) {
   var clickedX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
   var clickedY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
   var i = clickShapes.length;
   while (i-- && i >= 0) {
        if (clickedX < clickShapes[i].right && clickedX > clickShapes[i].left && clickedY > clickShapes[i].top && clickedY < clickShapes[i].bottom) {
             console.log('Circle nr ' + i + ' clicked at X: ' + clickedX + " Y:" + clickedY);
        }
    }
});
```